# Where to rent a portable hotspot in Doha, Qatar?

Tags: internet, wifi, qatar, doha

I'm going to Doha, Qatar, to see the start of the MotoGP championship.

Do you know if is it possible to rent a portable hotspot in the Hamad International Airport?

Alternatively, where can I find information about where to rent a portable hotspot in Doha?

Comment: Why not buy a local sim?..

Comment: because I'm going there for a short period of time, only 4 nights

Comment: Buying a sim card is a lot faster than renting a modem.

Comment: It is not possible to rent a local hotspot, you will have to get a pre-paid data-only SIM card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are few services that will do that for you :

- https://www.cellomobile.com/hotspot-rental/qatar.html
- https://www.xcomglobal.com/coverage-2/qatar

Then, while traveling, I usually use this application to get Wifi access :

- http://www.wifimap.io/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Laurent, I've seen both cellomobile and xcomglobal offers but it seems they don't have a sell point in Qatar. The standard approach is: order by internet, receive the device, use the device, return the device. Unfortunatly I don't have time to order it because the departure is imminent

Comment: Some offer a worldwide delivery. Not sure how long it takes. Then the other options are to buy a Sim card at the airport or use Wifimap which works well in a lot of countries (I used it in Qatar).